# Formula to check time spent on a task referencing minimum time allowed and a variable that will extend the minimum, if present

Tags: excel-formula

Looking for an excel formula that can verify time spent on task meets minimum requirements

We have objects that we monitor that have different monitoring times allowed, based on their size.  Each monitoring machine has a different "response time".  If the monitoring returns a value higher than 9, the size based minimum time, plus an additional twice the response time must be spent.  Each machine has 2 different probe lengths, and the lengths affect the response time.  Monitoring is usually done with one, and if the second is used instead, a comment that includes "EXT" will be entered.  I'd like to set up a sheet with formulas that will perform all of these checks.  We have a sheet set up with a formula that checks the time based minimum and if the value of 9 is exceeded, but the response time and if they use the second probe need to be entered manually.  All of the data comes from a couple of different sheets in the same workbook. The formula was written by someone else and it's way beyond what I know how to do.

```
=IF(M13>9,IF(P13="","", IF(K13="V", ($A$4+(INDEX('Minimum Visual Inspection Times'!$A$2:$P$15, MATCH(C13,'Minimum Visual Inspection Times'!$A$1:$A$15,TRUE), MATCH(D13,'Minimum Visual Inspection Times'!$A$2:$P$2,))))/(60*60*24), (($A$3+$A$2*2)+(INDEX('Minimum M21 Screening Times'!$A$2:$P$17, MATCH(C13,'Minimum M21 Screening Times'!$A$2:$A$17,TRUE), MATCH(D13,'Minimum M21 Screening Times'!$A$2:$P$2,))))/(60*60*24))),IF(P13="","", IF(K13="V", ($A$4+(INDEX('Minimum Visual Inspection Times'!$A$2:$P$15, MATCH(C13,'Minimum Visual Inspection Times'!$A$1:$A$15,TRUE), MATCH(D13,'Minimum Visual Inspection Times'!$A$2:$P$2,))))/(60*60*24), (($A$3)+(INDEX('Minimum M21 Screening Times'!$A$2:$P$17, MATCH(C13,'Minimum M21 Screening Times'!$A$2:$A$17,TRUE), MATCH(D13,'Minimum M21 Screening Times'!$A$2:$P$2,))))/(60*60*24))))
```

[image: Sample layout 1]

[image: Sample Layout 2]

[image: Sample Layout 3]

Comment: was hoping I'd be able to upload a couple of pictures to help clarify, but doesn't look like I can

Comment: Does that formula work? If it does, then begin to understand it by separating out the parts.

Comment: Upload your picture.  It will come through as just a link most likely.  We can edit the link so it will appear as an image in the question.  And DAM that is a long nested IF formula.  May want to consider breaking that into separate cells for your own sanity and to make your spreadsheet more readable for maintenance purposes.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/YCd3Aga)

Comment: the top image is from the "minimum M21 screening" tab.
the middle image is from the main "timestamp analyzer" tab, where all the calcs live.  This one in the P column specifically.
the bottom image is the "response" tab.

@SolarMike The formula works, and I think I have a decent idea how all of the parts work, but get lost in putting it together in a big IF statement

Comment: @Forwarded  don't know if I can break it up, because this one cell's input depends on all of the other factors

Answer (score 0):

So, every result is multiplied by "60*60*24" so take that outside all the IF() statements and replace with 86400.

Then consider that you have M13 and D13 getting results via index/match, so put those into fixed cells somewhere and just call the results into the IF() statements which will reduce the length.

Once you have that working then any further parts might be easier to implement.